# Moment inequality and second order stochastic dominance

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Suppose $\epsilon' = \epsilon + \eta$ where $E[\eta|\epsilon] = 0$, i.e. *$\epsilon$ second order stochastically dominates $\epsilon'$.*

Is it true that $E[(\epsilon')^{\alpha}] \geq E[(\epsilon)^{\alpha}]$ for all $\alpha > 0$? If not true in general, are there conditions under which it is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\epsilon'=\epsilon+\eta$ and $\mathsf{E}[\eta|\epsilon]=0$ we have 
$ \mathsf{E}[\epsilon'|\epsilon]=\mathsf{E}[\epsilon+\eta|\epsilon]=\epsilon$. Now using Jensen's inequality it is easy to get
$$\mathsf{E}[|\epsilon|^\alpha]=\mathsf{E}[|\mathsf{E}[\epsilon'|\epsilon]|^\alpha]\le \mathsf{E}[(\mathsf{E}[|\epsilon'||\epsilon])^\alpha]\le\mathsf{E}[|\epsilon'|^\alpha],\qquad \forall \alpha\ge 1.
$$